# How to deal with data Size error in tensorflow

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am making a tensor flow model shich takes a group of 6 values and outputs one.(testing and learning purposes)
Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
a=0
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=6, input_shape=(6,)))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
x=np.array(((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),(2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0),(3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0),(4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0)))
y=np.array((1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
print(x)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=100)
while True:
    a=float(input())
    print(model.predict(np.array((a,a,a,a,a,a))))
```

I get the following error:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 6 but received input with shape [None, 1]
```

when i find the shape of the input i am giving to the module,i get the right shape,being (6,0).
Any kind of help is appreciated. THank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 6 output neurons, but your targets have shape `(4, 1)`. Try again with 1 output neuron so the shapes of the output and labels match:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
a=0
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[6]))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
x=np.array(((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),
            (2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0),
            (3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0),
            (4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0)))
y=np.array((1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
print(x)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=100)
```

```
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 998us/sample - loss: 1.7085e-05
Epoch 98/100
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/sample - loss: 1.6974e-05
Epoch 99/100
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 748us/sample - loss: 1.6863e-05
Epoch 100/100
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 748us/sample - loss: 1.6752e-05
```

Or, keep your 6 neurons but add another layer after, with only 1 output neuron.

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
a=0
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=6, input_shape=[6]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1))
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',loss='mean_squared_error')
x=np.array(((1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0),
            (2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0,2.0),
            (3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0,3.0),
            (4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0,4.0)))
y=np.array((1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
print(x)
model.fit(x,y,epochs=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a `keras.layer.Input()` layer before your dense layer, because the dense layer has the same size as your input, but the models expects the last layer to match the size of your y values, which is `(None,1)`. The layer has to match your input and out output, so you need an extra layer. One for the input and one for the output.